# Is it possible to cast a SqlQuery results from Ebean to a Model (Bean)?

Tags: sql, playframework-2.1, ebean

Using Ebean (via Play Framework 2.1.1), I have to build a home made SQL query, but I'd like it to return directly a `List<MyModel>`, instead of a `List<SqlRow>` that I would have to query the database for each id from the result to have a `List<MyModel>`.

Is it possible to cast directly a SqlQuery/SqlRow to a Model ?

Actually, I do that :

```
SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT id FROM MyModel WHERE ...");
List<SqlRow> rows = query.findList(); // not directly possible.
List<MyModel> results = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
for (SqlRow row : rows) {
    results.add(MyModel.find.idEq(row.getLong("id)));
}
```

Ideally, it would be something like :

```
SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT id FROM MyModel WHERE ...");
List<MyModel> results = (List<MyModel>) query.findList(); // not directly possible.
```

This is not very efficient.

Comment: Do you need plain SQL or you can compose your query using finder methods? ( Model.find.where().eq(...).orderBy(...).findList() )

Comment: I need to compose it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse("SELECT id, value, ... FROM MyModel WHERE ...")
                  .columnMapping("id", "id")
                  .columnMapping("value", "value")
                  //...
                  .create();

Query<MyModel> query = Ebean.find(MyModel.class);
query.setRawSql(rawSql);
List<MyModel> result = query.findList();
```

---

Or using the finder:

```
Finder<Long, MyModel> finder = new Finder<Long, MyModel>(Long.class, MyModel.class);

List<MyModel> result = finder.where()
                             .eq("name", "Barack Obama")
                             //...
                             .findList();
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting it this late, but it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Comment: There is a special problem with Ebean when you use RawSql and after that, you want to limit the result (limit + page). It fails. Do you know how to work around ?

Comment: In case, any one is looking for ways to use connections other than *default*, you may use 
`Query<MyModel> query = Ebean.getServer("connectplus").find(MyModel.class)`

Comment: In my last comment, connectplus=yourConnectionName